# Cómo redireccionar con PHP

Tags: php

tengo esta página.

```
maximalearning.hardsoft.xyz
```

Qué debo hacer para que cada vez que un usuario intente navegar de esta forma...

```
maximalearning.hardsoft.xyz/index.php?id=start
```

Se redireccione a index.php y así con el resto de páginas. Pero es si hay algo luego del ".php" no sólo un "?variable=valor"

Gracias.

Comment: Y cómo sería con las otras páginas? esa parte no me queda clara. Qué servidor web es: Apache, nginx, etc..?

Comment: Con apache, gracias por responderme.

Comment: Con las otras páginas sería...

Comment: maximalearning.hardsoft.xyz/login.php?reg=jHLlvHoLlvfG89.... A maximalearning.hardsoft.xyz/login.php

Comment: Busca en internet sobre Apache Redirect htaccess. El archivo htaccess define el comportamiento del servidor apache, incluyendo las redirecciones. No hay una formula universal, por lo tanto tu pregunta es muy amplia, pero [este artículo de desarrolloweb.com](http://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/introduccion-htaccess.html) te puede ayudar. PD. Tal vez tu pregunta se cierre porque no cumple con los estándares de calidad del sitio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como se indica en los comentarios, al tener un servidor Apache, puedes usar el fichero `.htaccess` para definir redirecciones. Así lo que buscas sería algo como esto:

```
# Activa el modulo de redirecciones (mod_rewrite)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Si la solicitud incluye un query string, entonces redirecciona borrándolo
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [L,R=301]
```

La parte de activar el módulo de redirecciones no requiere mucha explicación, pero creo que sí hace falta más información en las otras dos líneas:

- `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .`: esta línea es una condición, la siguiente línea sólo se ejecutará si la URL solicitada  incluye un *query string* (la parte de ?nombre=valor)
- `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [L,R=301]`: esta línea es más interesante, básicamente lo que dice es:

  - redirige la URL sea lo que sea (`^(.*)$`)
  - a sí misma (`$1`)
  - sin el *query string* (el `?` detrás de `$1`; sin el `?`, el *query string* se mantendrá en la URL)
  - ésta será la última regla ejecutada (se indica con la señal `L`)
  - se debe redireccionar con el código 301 (la señal `R=301`; sin esta señal, se haría la redirección pero no se vería cambio alguno en la barra de direcciones).

---

Si no quieres usar `.htaccess` podrías realizar una redirección parecida desde PHP (aunque sería menos eficiente) añadiendo este pequeño script al principio de todos los ficheros PHP que quieres que eliminen su *query string*:

```
// si hay algún elemento en el query string
if (count($_GET) > 0) {
    // redirige a la misma página sin el query string
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, llegaste directo al punto.

Comment: Ahora bien, el htaccess, debe estar en todas las carpetas de mi hosting? O en una sola ubicación controla todo?